# How can I make my Java application on Windows use maximum heap memory available in the computer when user starts the application?

Tags: java, heap-memory

I need to release a Java application on Windows and I want it use the maximum heap memory available in the computer. How can I do it when it starts when it gets launched with user clicking on Windows?

Comment: Have a look at the command-line option `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=percent`, to specify maximum heap size, but be aware that your process also needs memory for its stack, and that your process is not alone on the machine.

Comment: You might want to reframe the issue in some other way. You seem to think that the user always has free memory. It is not uncommon for my (16GB) laptop to have only a fraction of it (as little as 1GB or less) free on busy days. People open tens of Chrome tabs. So in many ways, "everything available" may be 10 times less then what the computer is able to achieve (it could swap or whatever).